# Include and reference actual raw SVG in page

Tags: svg

We're using a platform that doesn't allow SVG files to be uploaded. We have external pages that are set up with code to automatically load an ID and we have toggle JavaScript as well for some of the elements.

Example:

```
<span class="spirit-form__checkbox-visual">
            <svg aria-label="check" class="spirit-icon spirit-form__checkbox-checked-icon" aria-hidden="true">
              <use xlink:href="/icons.svg#check">
              </use>
            </svg>
            <svg aria-label="minus" class="spirit-icon spirit-form__checkbox-indeterminate-icon" aria-hidden="true">
              <use xlink:href="/icons.svg#minus">
              </use>
            </svg>
          </span>
```

I attempted to reference them on another domain and they won't load - I believe due to cross-domain security.

Is there a means to put the raw XML contents of icons.svg within the file itself and then reference it within the span? This file is repeated throughout the page, so I don't want to have to paste it throughout.

Comment: One alternative method is to generate the SVG for icons client-side, wrapped in a Web Component. See https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: If you are asking for a server-side solution, just inline the SVG file content somewhere on the page body and set the size of the root `<svg>` to width = height = 0 with CSS.